# Why isn't this working?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, streamwriter

I am trying to just write an array of strings to a file, which SHOULD normally be an easy thing to do. However the following trivial code is throwing an IOException saying that the file is in use by another process. The problem is, the file doesn't even exist until this code is run. And I can guarantee you that there is no other process using the file. So how do I convince the stupid .NET framework that the file is not in use by another process and that it is okay to continue? Because this really shouldn't be that hard.

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(ListFileName);

foreach (string s in InfoLineList) 
{
    writer.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: Can you just use `File.WriteAllLines(path, InfoListList)`?  Maybe whatever file locking issues you're having will be avoided.

Comment: I could. But I really would like to know why does it think that the file is open somewhere else?

Comment: Okay, I changed it over to use WriteAllLines and it works now. I still don't understand why it didn't work the other way, and I would appreciate it if someone could explain that to me, but WriteAllLines does work.

Comment: The code provided should not cause the problem.  Even if you are not closing the file correctly, the file would be closed when the program exits.  If I was to try and solve it I would run the program in the debugger to see where the exception was thrown and what the local variables currently are.  You might want to turn off Window's file indexing service or adjust `writer` to explicitly lock the file.

Comment: In the future please come up with a better title than "Why isn't this working?"

Comment: It's almost certainly because you didn't close the file when you were done with it. And the next time you came around to open the file, it was already opened. Using `WriteAllLines` works because that opens the file, writes the lines, and then closes the file.

Comment: Sorry about the vague title.

Answer (score 4):

This might be because you're not closing the stream when you're done with it, so some handle is getting stuck open somewhere.  Perhaps the code is part of a web app, and the web server process keeps that lock around, or the code is being run multiple times.  I'd recommend using the stream in a `using` block:

```
using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(ListFileName))
{
   foreach (string s in InfoLineList) 
   {
       writer.WriteLine(s);
   }
}
```

This will make sure the `StreamWriter` is disposed of properly.

If you *really* want to know what has the file open, use [SysInternal's Handle tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655) to check.  I'd be willing to bet it's your own program.

Finally, as I said in my comments, the `File.WriteAllLines()` method can write an enumerable list of strings to a file all at once:

```
File.WriteAllLines(ListFileName, InfoListList);
```